# What would happen if a huge planet like Jupiter or Saturn was (or could be) terraformed?

Tags: jupiter, saturn

Even if these planets could be terraformed, it is very unlikely for this to be done in the future, if planets like Mars or Venus were terraformed. What would happen if Jupiter or Saturn could be terraformed?

Comment: Even if you were to define what terraforming means for a gas giant planet, "What would happen" is a question too broad for a Stack Exchange answere

Comment: Sorry, but this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: They are made of gases and thus do not have solid base.

Comment: @JamesK It's not so much that it doesn't make sense, as it's very vague and off-topic. There was for example idea of making a shell around Saturn, but that was sci-fi not astronomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gas giants cannot be terraformed unless they cease to be gas giants.

Let's assume, they have a solid core it is maybe 10 or 20 times the mass of Earth. However Jupiter has a mass of around 300 earth masses, so there is about 280 or 290 earth masses of gas on Jupiter. At the fictious surface of Jupiter's core, the gas is supercritical, thus so compressed that it's in the state where you cannot distinguish liquid from gas anymore due to the high pressure regime. And when you want to remove the excess gas, you remove most of Jupiter's mass and convert it into a so-called super-earth.

The ratio is not as big in favour of gas for Saturn (around 100 earth masses), but its solid core is assumed to be of similar size (here we actually know it has one). But still the atmosphere is at the core's boundary at the supercritical state, and removing that would remove the essence of Saturn from it along with most of its mass.

Settling on the moons of the gas giants sounds like a much more probably thing to do.